# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appVerificationDisabledForTesting') ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

why do i face this error when sending otp with firebase

these are codes

`import { RecaptchaVerifier, getAuth, signInWithPhoneNumber} from 'firebase/auth'; import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'`

```
sendCode() { 
    window.appVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
      "recaptcha-container",
      {
        size: "invisible",
      }
      , getAuth()
    );
    const appVerifier = window.appVerifier;
    this.setState({
      mobile: this.props.mobile,
      disabled: false,
    });
    var number = "+65 " + this.props.mobile;
    console.log(number);
    signInWithPhoneNumber(getAuth(), number, appVerifier)
      .then(function (confirmationResult) {
        console.log("Success");
        // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
        // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
        window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
        this.setState({confirmResult: confirmationResult});
        console.log(confirmationResult);
```

```
componentDidMount() {
    initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }
```

```
   <div id="recaptcha-container" />
```

i keep receiving this error
[image]

anybody can let me know where im doing wrong please ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sendCode() {
    this.setState({
      mobile: this.state.mobile,
      disabled: false,
    });
    var number = "+65 " + this.state.mobile;
    console.log(number);

    window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(getAuth(), "recaptcha-container", {
      'size': 'invisible'
    });
    const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;

    signInWithPhoneNumber(getAuth(), number, appVerifier)
    .then(function (confirmationResult) {
      console.log("Success");
      window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
      console.log(confirmationResult);
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this would help,

```
import { getAuth, RecaptchaVerifier } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(auth, 'recaptcha-container', 
{
  'size': 'normal',
});
```

according to firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#use-the-recaptcha-widget) first parameter is `Auth` then `containerOrId` then `RecaptchaParameters`

Comment: it doesn't seem to work  :(

Comment: @Natasha, which version of firebase sdk are you using ?

Comment: "firebase": "^10.5.0", this is my firebase version, im using this firebase for my react website

Comment: @Natasha, what error did you see after switching the order of parameters ?

Comment: i have managed to fix the error! thank you for your contribution, appreciate it alot :)

Comment: @Natasha, what was the error ?

Comment: I have posted the answer, i changed the appVerifier to recaptchaVerifier and also remove d getAuth() in the window.recaptchaVerifier

Comment: @Natasha, i think changing `window.appVerifier` to `window.recaptchaVerifier` doesn't matter, i think changing the order of the parameter is what worked. can you clarify and let me know ?